# Selecting rows based on time interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

Lefts say i have a table - > `comments`

```
id| comment | thread_id |         time       |  
1    xyz        1         2013-1-10 19:21:17
2    xyz        1         2013-1-11 19:21:17
3    xyz        2         2013-1-14 19:21:17
4    xyz        2         2013-2-10 19:21:17
5    xyz        1         2013-2-10 19:21:17
6    xyz        1         2013-2-10 19:21:17
7    xyz        1         2013-2-10 19:21:17
8    xyz        1         2013-4-10 19:21:17
9    xyz        1         2013-4-10 19:21:17
10   xyz        1         2013-6-10 19:21:17
```

Now i want to get total No of comments `COUNT()` in a particular `thread_id` at **interval of each month**

So that i have an array something like this -  >
(if we take `thread_id` = 1)

```
$total[0] => 2 
$total[1] => 6
$total[2] => 6 
$total[3] => 8
$total[4] => 8
$total[5] => 9
```

...so on till $total[11] => 9

I will be able to do that by 12 queries for each month but that's not too  good .

Anyone can do it with one single  query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce a full range of months, you would use some device like the following, basically a list of all the possible values, then attach the data to this via a left join:

```
-- just an example
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      select 1  as th union all
      select 2  as th union all
      select 3  as th union all
      select 4  as th union all
      select 5  as th union all
      select 6  as th union all
      select 7  as th union all
      select 8  as th union all
      select 9  as th union all
      select 10 as th union all
      select 11 as th union all
      select 12
      ) mon
      LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        MONTH(time)      AS Month
                      , COUNT(thread_id) AS No_of_Comment
                  FROM comments
                  GROUP BY
                        MONTH(time)
            ) dat
                  ON mon.th = dat.month
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using a group by statement:-

Here is the Sql for that:-

```
Select month(time) as Month, COUNT(thread_id) as No_of_Comment from comments group by month(time)
```

Comment: Obviously, if there are no comments for a given month then that month will be absent from the result.

Comment: You could also use `UNION` to make all months visible.

Comment: what to do if i need to show month with no comments also ? @nobodynoone

Comment: Use `UNION` 12 times and connect it with your table, then you can distinct on month values with order by number of comments :)